# How to find which collider with same tag is touching my character firstly when multiple colliders are touching my character same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm trying to figure out which collider with same tag is touching my character firstly when multiple colliders are touching my character same time.

```
if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "enemy") {
            hit = true;
            rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.150f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            if (transform.position.x-col.transform.gameObject.transform.position.x < 0)
            {
                rgd.AddForce(-1*rgd.transform.right * 40);
            }
            else
            {
                rgd.AddForce(1*rgd.transform.right * 40);
            }

            if (Mathf.Approximately (angle, 0)) {
                Destroy (col.transform.gameObject);
                damage = 0;
            } else {
                damage = 25;
            }
            enemydamageSound.Play();
        }
```

Comment: Make an empty list of Colliders, append the other collider to the end of the list when a collision begins, remove it when the collision ends, and you can know which collider has been colliding for the longest just by indexing the first collider in the list.

Comment: You can add your code below [as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so it can help people who come here with the same question :)  you might even get some upvotes for it

Comment: If multiple colliders are touching, each will have triggered the oncollissionenter/oncollisionstay - just put the code in the appropriate.

Comment: Thanks all of you,i've solved problem and shared what code i'm write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a few code.Here is my new code:

```
private int jumpCount = 0;

if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            isGround = true;
            jumpped = true;
            jumpCount = 0;
        }

if (col.transform.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
    {
        hit = true;
        if (!isGround && jumpCount == 0)
        {
            rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.150f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpCount++;
        }
        if (transform.position.x - col.transform.gameObject.transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            if (jumpCount == 0)
            {
                rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
            rgd.AddForce(-1 * rgd.transform.right * 40);
        }
        else
        {
            if (jumpCount == 0)
            {
                rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
            rgd.AddForce(1 * rgd.transform.right * 40);
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(angle, 0))
        {
            Destroy(col.transform.gameObject);
            damage = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            damage = 25;
        }
        enemydamageSound.Play();
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. Imagine the following sequence of events: collissionEnter, collissionEnter, collissionExit, collissionEnter. How many colliders are in `myCollider`? How many are colliders should there be?

Comment: i noticed just now.I think there are problems in unity's collider system.Whenever ı jump on two object(enemy) side by side with same tag,my jump code getting work two times same time and then my character going high because of jump code work two times.And i couldn't solve it.

Comment: In a contest between "Unity's code is wrong" and "your code is wrong" I'm going to bet that the problem is in your code, not Unity's, every time. Not that Unity doesn't have bugs, but that the probability that any given issue is a bug in Unity's code is virtually nil.

Comment: some changes that might fix the problem: **1.** Don't do `myCollider.Clear();`, instead do `myCollider.Remove(col.otherCollider);`. **2.** Instead of doing `myCollider.Add(col.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>());` you can just do `myCollider.Add(col.otherCollider);`,

Comment: Okay,i removed myCollider then add jumpCount variable.When i press space and i'm not on ground and touched a enemy,my jump code will be start one times.